Elastic-builder for R shiny
I am trying to source Elastic-builder library in R shiny using this cdn link: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/elastic-builder@2.29.0/src/index.js". But this is not sourcing the library as expected. I have a javascript code to be integrated to R shiny. So for that to work I need elastic-builder library.
While trying to source the package, this is the error I am getting in the console
enter image description here

This is a library for Node. It won't work in Shiny.

This library is a NPM package, that is, it is conceived to work in Node.js, but not in vanilla JavaScript ("normal" JavaScript).
That said, it is possible to transform a NPM package to an ordinary JavaScript file. For example, you can try browserify.
Firstly, do a global installation of browserify:
npm install -g browserify

Now install Elastic Builder:
npm install elastic-builder

Now try to transform the NPM package by using browserify; in a console, run these commands:
echo "global.esb = require('elastic-builder');" > in.js
browserify in.js -o elasticBuilder.js

Now, if you are lucky, you can use the generated file elasticBuilder.js in Shiny:
tags$script("elasticBuilder.js")

In the browserified file elasticBuilder.js, there is a variable named esb, which we defined above. It corresponds to require('elastic-builder').
Again, I'm not sure this will work (I think it won't, because I did a little search with Google, and I found nothing).
